# set home w./ commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a `/sethome` kind of thing. I don't think you can test what a player *says*, but I want an item that can be thrown, then mark the X Y and Z cords. Could I do that, if so *how*, and will it require a command block for *every* block in the world?

Comment: So just to clarify, you want to mark a players coordinates when a block is thrown?

Comment: Well, I guess it could be done by having a command block continuously following a player around (above or below the player), and constantly testing for a thrown item in a certain radius. (Alternatively, you could check if the player used to have an item and now doesn't, but then they could have just put it in a chest) If it detects one, it can `/sethome` at the player's coords. I know it's not perfect, but I think it can get the job done. If you want me to show you the commands, tell me, and I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to /sethome in vanilla Minecraft.  This does not require you to throw a block, but I think it may be worth your time.  Watch this video:

With this you can `/sethome`, `/tpa`, and `/back`